# Размещение блочного элемента внутри строчного

Tags: html, css

Необходимо контейнер, в котором будут распологаться блочные элементы, сделать ссылкой. Cсылка это строчный элемент, можно присвоить display: block; но что будет с валидностью html. Какое решение является правильным?

Comment: hmtl5 это допускает. Объявите документ правильно и валидатор w3c все поймет верно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы документ был валидным используйте span вместо div для заполнения ссылки, и присвойте ему dispay:block. В таком случае html будет валидным, так как span по умолчанию строчный.

```css
a {
  display:block;
}

span {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <span>text</span>
</a>
```